Linux extract .zip and preserve all original files timestamps (created/modified/accessed)
It's possible to restore original file timestamps during extraction on linux? I'm tested .zip extraction using 7z, unzip, unar, but only modification date is restored.
Environment:

Linux Mint 22
Filesystem: ext4
tested.zip: it's really keeps all original timestamps creation/modification/access (it's visible e.g. in PeaZip), archive created at Win via 7z.


Which version of 7z did you use on Linux?

7-zip 23.01 (x64)


Create times (btime) are not available on all file systems (your Ext4 does support them) and can be set only by root. Linux in 2025 still has no API for that. star could be used for that but again only for the root user. It does that by changing system time for each unpacked file.
Modified times (mtime) should work out of the box.
Last access times (atime) should normally work. If they don't, your utilities simply don't bother to set them or you've not archived them.

